# How to hide react native component upon toggling

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I currently have several elements on top of a background like this:

[Layout 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZQ2P.png)

Element 1 & 2 are grouped together, just like 3&4. After toggling, I want the layout to end up so that elements 1 and 3 are hidden and the background comes on top. I try hiding 1 and 3 using a props that tells whether it has been toggled or not and then I put that element behind the green background using `zIndex`:

```
{props.toggled && 
    <View style={{zIndex:-3}}>
        <Element1>
    </View>}
```

However it ends up like this where elements 2 and 4 stretches and takes over most of the space:

[Layout 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z815l.png)

I need it to look like this instead:

[Layout 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLDEx.png)

Anyone has some good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use opacity and if the elements are touchable disable pointer events:

```js
<View
  style={{ opacity: props.toggled ? 0 : 1 }}
  pointerEvents={props.toggled ? "none" : "auto"}
>
  <Element1>
</View>
```

Comment: Will this allow the background underneath to be "pressed"? Underneath these elements are an image carousel.

Comment: @smolkitty yes, that's the purpose of pointerEvents in there

Comment: @smolkitty check [this part of the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents) for more information on how pointerEvents change the view behaviour.